# ServiceNow "Display Value"

Tags: servicenow

I am not able to understand the meaning of "Display Value" in Service Now. 
I found some of the documents on the web. But that was not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it as choosing what field to use as the "Name" of the record. It's what shows up in reference fields, when you call the [GlideRecord.getDisplayValue()](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=GlideRecord#getDisplayValue) function, and other places in the system.

Let's say for simplicity you have a table called "Problem" with 3 fields:

- Number
- Creation date
- Created by

You're on the "Incident" table, and you want to link the incident to a certain problem. You open up the reference picker and choose the problem from the popup list, but when you return to the incident form the value showing in the field "Problem" says "2017-05-08 10:30:50". This indicates that the "Display Value" field is set to "Creation date". The incident is linked to the correct problem, but it's just the "Display Value" is not set correctly.

If you updated the "Problem" table so that it's "Display Value" field was "Number", then when you chose the problem to link your incident to, the "Problem" field on the incident record would show up for example like "PRB000005".

There can only be one display value per table. If you change a field to be the display value for that table, any other field on that table with display value = `true` will be set to display value = `false`.